# using onCreateOptionsMenu with aChartEngine

Tags: android, android-activity, achartengine, android-menu

I'm trying to include a menu in my Graph view. I have the graph working perfectly, and on the main activity, I have the menu working fine. I just can't seem to get the menu to show up in my graphing activity.

Here is the code inside LineGraph.java:

```
public class LineGraph extends Activity {
        //me trying to initialize the menu
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_graph, menu);
        return true;
    }

public Intent getIntent(Context context){

    //data
    int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; //x values
    int[] y = {30,34,45,80,57,77,89,100,111,123,145};//yvalues

    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Caffeine Level");
    for(int i = 0; i<x.length;i++){
        series.add(x[i], y[i]);
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series); 

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Title");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("ytitle");

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph");

    return intent;
}
```

}

I'm sure this is a simple change, but I have tried searching, and I cannot seem to find the answer. The obvious things (at least to me) have been checked. For example, I am using the correct R, the activity_graph exists inside the /res/menu directory. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!